# Access native JSON object when JSON2 has overloaded it

Tags: javascript, json, dom, cross-domain, bookmarklet

I am implementing a bookmarklet which communicates with a iframe through a JSON-RPC protocol.

However some sites, such as cnn.com load JSON2 into `window.JSON` although the browser already has a native JSON object.

The problem is that within my iframe I would not like to follow the same bad practice, and JSON2 does not seem to be compatible with the native JSON on Mozilla Firefox and Chrome:

So when I run stringify on the native JSON and JSON2, I get the following results:

```
JSON.stringify({key: "value"})
```

#### JSON2

```
{key:"value"}
```

#### Native JSON

```
{"key":"value"}
```

(Key is wrapped in `"`)

---

The problem is that the native JSON does not like it when the `"` is missing in the JSON2-produced string and throws an error:

Mozilla Firefox: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'`

Google Chrome: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token k`

To solve the problem for good, I need to make sure that I use the same JSON library to encode the string as I do for decoding it.

One way of doing it is to make sure to use JSON2 or JSON3 on both sides, but I'd like to use  the native json library where possible.

So now that sites like cnn.com have overriden the native JSON library, how can I get back to it?

I could perhaps create an iframe that points to the same domain and fetch the JSON object from its `contentWindow`, but that would be highly inefficient.

Isn't there a better way?

Comment: [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) **do** exactly wrap key with double quote...

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano well not what ever version it is that CNN has installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if i understand your problem correctly

if you place an empty iframe like this

```
<iframe id="testFrame" name="testFrame" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

then you can also call from js

```
testFrame.JSON.stringify(obj);
```

the only problem is that if you use it in `https:` src could be `javascript:false` if you need to support IE6

EDIT: I still think i don't deserve the answer being accepted, so i've come up with a modified version of your code

```
(function($) {
  var frm;
  $.getNative = function(objectName, callback) {
    if (!frm) {
      frm= $("<iframe>", {
        src: "javascript:false",
        style: "display:none;"
      }).appendTo("body").load(function(){
        callback(this.contentWindow[objectName]);
        // $(this).remove(); <-- this is commented to cache the iframe
      });
    }
    callback(frm[0].contentWindow[objectName]);
  }
})(jQuery)
```

this will enable you to use `$.getNative()` multiple times in a document without recreating the frame each time.

Comment: The questioner mentions this trick, but is hoping to avoid dynamically creating an iframe. Alas, I am unable to find another solution, so this is probably the approach to take.

Comment: @LukeDennis i'm sorry i can't help :(

Comment: Well didn't realize `about:blank` or `javascript:false` would work as it would have been cross domain. So it is an improvement as it doesn't need to hit `window.location.href` as I've originally intended... +1

Comment: Guys, maybe you do know the answer to the question why the returned value can be undefined? I asked for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209246/how-to-restore-native-browser-object-without-creating-iframe

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution is to use an iframe, but as Crisim Il Numenoreano has pointed out, it should be pointed to `about:blank` or `javascript:false`. This seems to work fine so far:

```
function getNative(objectName, callback) {
    $("<iframe>", {
        src: "javascript:false",
        style: "display:none;"
    }).appendTo("body").load(function(){
        callback(this.contentWindow[objectName]);
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

//Use like this:

getNative("JSON", function(JSON) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({key: "value"}));
});
```

Note that for bookmarklets jquery must be fetched from reliable sources and protected within a local scope too.